# BreezeJS Predicate: how to search for multiple data types?

Tags: javascript, types, breeze, predicate

I have a .NET server-side class with multiple datatype like string, int, decimal and Date. On the client side i want to search for each columns, but Breeze predicate can search for 1 datatype at a time.

> public partial class Validation {

```
    public Guid ValidationID { get; set; } (dont search for this field)
    public int Integer { get; set; }
    public string String { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BeforeDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AfterDate { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public decimal? CreditCard { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Then i tried

> breeze.Predicate.or(predicate1, predicate2, predicate3)

but it returned bad request.

Then i use javascript to check if the results data return 0 object, i'll search for another type (string then numeric then date)

**Question 1**: Is there a way to convert Breeze data to string, so that i'll need 1 predicate for all fields and search for the string only?

> for example: breeze.Predicate.create('date'**.toString()**, 'contains', '09/15')

**Question 2**: If there're no answers to q1, is there a better/decent way to search for multiple datatype with Breeze?

Any answers are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put each predicate inside a or (only the 1st one you'll don't have to put inside a or) and concat them like this example:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Validation");
var predicate1 = breeze.Predicate.create("ValidationID", "contains", searchText);
var predicate2 = breeze.Predicate.create("Email", "contains", searchText);
query.where(predicate1.or(predicate2));
manager.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: it seems to work but i did this way already: i create 2 predicates:
`function stringPredicateFn(filterValue) {
return Predicate.create('string'.toString(), 'contains', filterValue)
.or('email', 'contains', filterValue)
.or('phone', 'contains', filterValue)
.or('uRL', 'contains', filterValue)
.or('zip', 'contains', }`
and
`function numericPredicateFn(filterValue) {
return Predicate.create('age', '==', filterValue)
.or('integer', '==', filterValue)
.or('creditCard', '==', filterValue);}`
then i query: .**where(numericPredicate.or(stringPredicate))**
first predicate ok, second 400 bad request

Comment: Then it could be a problem with your webservice. Did you take a look at the error message from the service? If it is a WCF-Service you need to put config.UseVerboseErrors = true; inside the InitializeService-Function.

Comment: I use .NET API controller with OData and Breeze together, the problem occurs with the queryString/OData server, let me look into that. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: i got this error when trying to search for 1 string(email) and 1 numeric(age) object:


`A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'.`

it's ok to search for integer like "123", but error occurs when i search for string like "abc"

code:
`var pred = Predicate.create('age', '==', searchText).or('email', 'contains', searchText)`
`breeze.EntityQuery.from('Validations').where(pred)...

Comment: So this error doesn't relate to your first question I think.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to search on non text fields with string operators like 'startsWith' 'endsWith' or 'contains' and similarly you won't be able to search string or boolean fields with operators like 'gt' or 'lt'.  This is because EF ( along with Mongo and other ORM providers) do not provide the underlying support on the server queries like this.

What you can do is query for all fields of the same type by or'ing your predicates together: ( similar to Sebastian's answer ). So for strings something like this:

```
var Predicate = breeze.Predicate;
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Validation");

var searchText = 'findMe';
// Predicate.create works as well
var p1 = new Predicate("Email", "contains", searchText); 
var p2 = new Predicate("Phone", "contains", searchText);
var p3 = new Predicate("Zip", "contains", searchText);
query.where(Predicate.or[ p1, p2, p3] );
```

and for dates:

```
searchDate = new Date(2014,0,1);
var p1 = new Predicate("BeforeDate", "==", searchDate); 
var p2 = new Predicate("AfterDate", "==", searchDate);
query.where(Predicate.or[ p1, p2] );
```

you can also use any data type appropriate functions within the query, i.e.

```
var searchYear = 2014; 
// Predicate.create works as well
var p1 = new Predicate("year(BeforeDate)", "==", searchYear); 
var p2 = new Predicate("year(AfterDate)", "==", searchYear);
query.where(Predicate.or[ p1, p2] );
```

you can also 'or' together predicates of different types but you obviously won't be using the same search 'value'. However, you could do something like this.

```
var searchDate = new Date(2014,0,1);
var searchText = searchDate.toString();

// Predicate.create works as well
var p1 = new Predicate("Email", "contains", searchText); 
var p2 = new Predicate("BeforeDate", "==", searchDate); 
query.where(Predicate.or[ p1, p2] );
```